# Oracle Join across tables to count 'outstanding invoices'

Tags: sql

I'm trying to find "the number of outstanding invoices for a given contract rate".

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0d13d/1)  (updated with ujjwal's answer to add a distinct)

You'll notice I have 350 outstanding invoices which is a lot more than the 14 I expected so I guess I haven't restricted the INNER JOIN's correctly...

Any ideas would be great thanks (sorry I'm rusty on SQL), this is for the latest version of Oracle.

Wayne

Comment: That SQLFiddle is not working for me—specifically `A-00900: invalid SQL statement : con.id = c.contractor_id`. A brief look at the schema and it seems that  c.contractor_id is VARCHAR2(13) and con.id is NUMBER(22)?

Comment: Thanks Rob, that was SQL Fiddle Text to DDL not quite getting it the way I needed it (strangely it still worked for me, but I've updated it too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try selecting only distinct entries:

```
 SELECT
        r.id AS rate_id,
        COUNT(distinct mi.id) AS outstanding_invoices           **change here**
    FROM
        contract_rate r
    INNER JOIN
        contract c ON r.contract_id = c.id
    INNER JOIN
        contractor con ON con.id = c.contractor_id
    INNER JOIN
        maintenance_item item ON item.contract_rate_id = r.id        
    INNER JOIN
        maintenance_invoice mi ON mi.contractor_id = c.contractor_id AND mi.status = 'Awaiting Approval'
    GROUP BY
        r.id
```

Comment: I've updated the SQL Fiddle with the distinct and indeed that does work thanks!